# How to prevent SupportV4 (Fragment)Tabhost creating its own Fragment at TabChange?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a problem with the Fragments within the SupportV4 tabhost that loads two Fragments during a single tab change. (Tabhost used; android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost)

The problem happens because I want to use MVVMCross and its ViewModels, so I need to load ViewModels within the Fragments (that are inside the tab).

To clear things up I used the following flow;
- Load ActionActivity and then load the Fragment to hold Tabs
- AddTabs (within Fragment)
- Add every TabChange switch the Fragment with the SupportFragmentManager

My Fragment that holds the Tabs has the following:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var rootView = this.BindingInflate(LayoutId, null);

    activityTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
    activityTabHost.Setup(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, Resource.Id.realtabcontent);

    var savedcurrentTabTag = string.Empty;

    AddTabs(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedcurrentTabTag = savedInstanceState.GetString(SavedTabIndexStateKey);
        activityTabHost.SetCurrentTabByTag(savedcurrentTabTag);
    }

    if (lookup.Any()) {
        OnTabChanged(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedcurrentTabTag) ? lookup.First().Key : savedcurrentTabTag);
    }

    activityTabHost.SetOnTabChangedListener(this);

    return rootView;
}
```

TabLoading (one by one)

```
private static void AddTab(Fragment fragment, // Check incomming (was MvxTabsFragmentActivity)
TabHost tabHost,
Android.Widget.TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec,
MvxTabFragmentInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.SetContent(new MvxTabFragmentFactory(fragment.Activity));
    var tag = tabSpec.Tag;

    // Check to see if we already have a CachedFragment for this tab, probably
    // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
    // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
    tabInfo.CachedFragment = fragment.ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (tabInfo.CachedFragment != null && !tabInfo.CachedFragment.IsDetached) {
        var ft = fragment.ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Detach(tabInfo.CachedFragment);
        ft.Commit();
        fragment.ChildFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
    }

    tabHost.AddTab(tabSpec, Class.FromType(tabInfo.FragmentType), tabInfo.Bundle);
}
```

Tab Change:

```
public virtual void OnTabChanged(string tag) {
    var newTab = lookup[tag];
    if (currentTab != newTab) {
        var ft = ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        OnTabFragmentChanging(tag, ft);
        if (currentTab != null) {
            if (currentTab.CachedFragment != null) {
                ft.Detach(currentTab.CachedFragment);
            }
        }

        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.CachedFragment == null) {
                // CAUTION!!!
                // This adds a NEW fragment to the ChildFragmentManager, but the TabHost creates its own Fragment to! 
                // (that one needs to be cancled, regocnized by the lack of a ViewModel)
                newTab.CachedFragment = Instantiate(Activity, FragmentJavaName(newTab.FragmentType), newTab.Bundle);
                FixupDataContext(newTab);
                ft.Add(TabContentId, newTab.CachedFragment, newTab.Tag);
            } else {
                FixupDataContext(newTab);
                ft.Attach(newTab.CachedFragment);
            }
        }

        currentTab = newTab;
        currentTabTag = (newTab != null) ? newTab.Tag : string.Empty;
        ft.Commit();
        ChildFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
    }

    TabHost.ViewTreeObserver.RemoveOnTouchModeChangeListener(TabHost);
}
```

As you see I currently load my own Fragment and then attach the ViewModel to the Fragment. Good to say that the ViewModels already exist, that come from a parent ViewModel that hold 4 ViewModels, one for each Tab.

BUT! The TabHost creates his own Fragment during a TabChange, but without the ViewModel because its not automaticly loaded in that MvxFragment.

This is my work-around, to cancel the Fragment in that hasnt got a ViewModel
(otherwise I would get to Fragments on top of eachother).

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (ViewModel == null) {
        return null;
    }

    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.GroupedFragmentView, null);
}
```

This is a work around, I want to have more control of the Tabhost that creates the Fragment.

Does anyone know how to get into the SupportV4 tabhost to control the Fragment creation? or doen anyone else have a good solution instead of my workaround?

Comment: Use a ViewPager with a ViewPagerIndicator instead. Tabs are old school...

Comment: Yep, the ViewPager was on the agenda. But if there is a good/easy solution for Tabs that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be the work-around; (but a better solution would be the suggestion of Cheesebaron)

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (ViewModel == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.GroupedFragmentView, null);
}
```